# Como posso somar dias a uma data selecionada pelo usuário?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker

eu estou começando agora na programação, e estou com dificuldade pra somar alguns dias em uma data selecionada pelo usuário. O que eu gostaria de fazer é, após o usuario selecionar uma data, acrescentar mais 60 dias e em seguida mostrar a data já com os 60 dias acrescidos. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        mDateFormat = findViewById(R.id.dataFormat);
        resultado = findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        btn_Calc = findViewById(R.id.btn_Calc);

        mDateFormat.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    onDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            datePickerDialog.show();
        });

        onDateSetListener = (view, year1, month1, dayOfMonth) -> {
            month1 = month1 +1;
            String date = dayOfMonth+"/"+ month1 +"/"+ year1;
            mDateFormat.setText(date);
            data = date;
        };


        btn_Calc.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            resultado.setText(data);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Usa a classe DateTime:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).